# gtk_window_is_active() not working as expected

Tags: gtk, gtk2

I call gtk_window_is_active(wnd) and always receive 0, even when I know for sure that wnd is active and receiving keyboard input. What is the cause and where is the remedy for this?

In fact, I run gtk_window_list_toplevels() and iterate over the list - and gtk_window_is_active() returns 0 for each of them!

Answer (score 1):

When you create a GtkWindow it is still in the 'unrealized' state. You have to call show() on it and let the main loop run, then the window gets realized. So if you call gtk_window_is_active after creating the windows, but before the main loop has chances to run, you will get false.

Comment: lb90, at the time my code runs, all my windows are realized and mapped, and fully visible on the screen. In fact, my code is invoked in response to a button click inside this window.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Emmanuele Bassi, Gnome Foundation staff, I figured it out: **the problem is that my focus-in-event handler returned 1 (TRUE), and thus prevented the default GTK behaviour**. It turned out (something not obvious) that keeping track of the active window is part of that default behavior that i unknowingly overrode.

So, I changed focus-in-event handler of my windows to return FALSE (0), and ever since gtk_window_is_active() works like a clock.

I came to realize an unhelpful (to my task) detail: gtk_window_is_active() only works AFTER all focus-in-event handlers have completed working. Well, I have a mouse click handler that activates some other window, and then needs to check if a certain window is active (these things belong to different objects and different modules, yet are executed within one click hadler invocation). In my case gtk_window_is_active() is useless: it returs FALSE for the active window until  after my click handler has finished and the focus-in-handlers (mine and the default) have finished, too.

Comment: Great! For the last part, you should use using g_signal_connect_after() then. That way it should work ;)